# Audit tables in different databases

Tags: postgresql, audit, log

I am studying ways to implement audit tables to my PostgreSQL database and would like to know if it is possible to make a trigger for the data to be written to a table in a database other than the source database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of the additional module [`dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html). Install once per database (the one where the trigger is executed):

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

You need superuser privileges (in the database cluster where the trigger runs) for some of the involved functionality.

Since you want to write *to* the external database, you will probably want to use [`dblink_exec()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-exec.html). The manual has code examples.

[Or try a search here for more dblink examples.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:answer%20%5Bpostgresql%5D%20%2bdblink&submit=search)

Note that you cannot `ROLLBACK` what you have written with dblink to an external database. A local exception *after* the external write does not undo what's written in the foreign database.

Comment: Thank you, i'll read more about it and perform some tests.